# importing maven project with m2e ignores active profile

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, m2e

I have defined a profile in my POM. Now I want to import this project with m2e. When I do so the default profile is ignored. On the other hand If I set the profile explicitly before import which profiles should be active (Import Maven Project > Advanced) then the project is imported with the correct profile.

Why is the profile is ignored when importing with m2e? If maven can determine the correct profile on command line why can't it do so with M2E?

```
    <profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>important-profile</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
                    <build>
                    ... important stuff ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider opening an issue at [m2eclipse - Support](https://www.eclipse.org/m2e/support/) because it is [free software](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-list.html#EPL).